# Wiring confusion in joining two cables with 5.5 x 2.1 mm DC male ends, please explain

Tags: wiring, bad-wiring

I've got a 12V powerbank that I would like to use with a 12v device. The power bank output and the device both require 5.5 x 2.1mm male plugs.

I've actually got some random cables and have found two of these exact cables. Now for the weird thing, when I test for continuity with a multimeter, it is different for these cables - so for one cable, I get continuity when I use the two outside surfaces of both the 5.5mm ends. However, on the other cable, I get continuity when I use the outside surface of one end and the inside surface of the other end. Does this not matter for a DC circuit? So if I randomly join together two cables with 5.5mm ends, then I don't need to worry how it is joined or should I make sure the continuity is inside part to inside part and outside with outside?

Comment: Please add description of polarity of the DC plugs at both devices. The polarities they have determine how you should wire the connectors.

Comment: I'm assuming the polarities are the same as the ends are identical

Comment: Some devices have positive at center pin, some have negative at the center pin. So please don't assume anything - if you knew you would not be asking here, right?

Comment: Some equipment with those coaxial power connectors are center positive, and some are center negative (and even AC is possible, I think).  You have to look for markings on the equipment to see which polarity (and voltage) it requires (or provides, in the case of power supplies)

Comment: Hmm, now I am confused. Let's start off with this - do I need to make sure the positive from the power bank goes into the positive of the device I'm hoping to power? If it is reversed, would the device not get power?

Comment: And if this is correct, that is positive to positive is a requirement, then what is an easy way to determine which is positive of the device I am trying to power if it is not stated on the device?

Comment: A reversed input voltage will probably destroy the device! In order to find out the polarity when there is no label on it you have to reverse engineer the electronics inside.

Comment: ok, can I test if it's positive by using my multimeter - so I would plug in the cable to the power bank and then check if I get a positive voltage with my multimeter on the unplugged end? Then for the input device, I have the original AC/DC adapter for the device, so I could just test the polarity of this adapter in the same way - does that sound correct?

Comment: The device I am trying to power with the powerbank has positive inside polarity. So I take it I just need to make sure that whatever cable I use from the power bank, that the end that goes into the device to which I am supplying the power is has inside positive polarity - correct?

Comment: Yes, as long as the powered device gets the correct polarity, it will be fine. Just look at the markings on the devices, or their manual about connector polarity. At least provide information what make/model devices they are, and put links to photos or manuals of them. Or take photos and put them here.

Comment: Yes, I just checked the polarity of the powered device by checking the polarity of the AC/DC adapter that came with the device. The end 5.5mm plug of the adapter is positive on the inside. So I'll just make sure the positive from the power supply terminates to a positive inside of the barrel connector plug that will go into the powered device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polarity matters in DC. If it is incorrect, either it just won't work, or it will get permanently damaged.

As long as the powered device gets voltage with correct polarity, everything should be fine.